# When using GET in php for data generated with jQuery's $.param(data), there are %5B and %5D

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have JSON data called rowdata that I use in an ajax call. If I use:

```
JSON.stringify(rowdata)
```

it looks like like the following:

```
{"Description":"qwerty","Code":"12345","Size":"11","Colour":"green"}
```

I do send it to php and use a GET statement (Joomla's

```
JRequest::getVar("Description",  "", "", "")
```

statement) to get the elements of rowdata but I cannot succeed.

If I look at the ajax data that has been send I do have the following:

```
rowdata%5BDescription%5D=qwerty
```

etc. after applying:

```
$.param(data)
```

I have used many version instead of "Description", but to no avail. I tried to get rowdata on its own and access its elements, but no success. I cannot find out what the %5B and %5D means, searching for that is problematic with the % sign. Anyone who can help to get the values of Description, Code, etc. in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending JSON, but trying to parse it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Don't convert the object to JSON.

```
$.get('example.php', {"Description":"qwerty","Code":"12345","Size":"11","Colour":"green"});
```

Comment: I use an application that provides these data in JSON format. If I use the solution above and enter the data like `{"Description":"qwerty","Code":"12345","Size":"11","Colour":"green"}` it works but if I use `JSON.stringify(rowdata)` to produce the same result, then it doesn't work. I displayed the result of stringify in an alert and it looks identical to the data that I entered (`{"Description":"qwerty","Code":"12345","Size":"11","Colour":"green"}`). Therefore it is strange for me that it does not work using stringify.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `%5B` is `[` and `%5D` is `]`. Your URL is encoding special characters. It's called [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use JSON if you want to push data with get... otherwise it will be encoded to satisfy JSON format and you will get those entities.

```
$.get('target.php', {"Description":"qwerty","Code":"12345","Size":"11","Colour":"green"});
```